# Adding Functionality: on click add post title into textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am having trouble adding this function to my site. I have CustomPostTypes with Products and a simple form on the site, what I would like to do is on click storing a variable with the post title and appending it at the textarea in the form. (  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGERm.jpg how it should work ).

I am a complete beginner with jQuery and Javascript so I would really appreciate if someone can gimme a guide on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2 id="post-title">Cake name 2</h2>

<button id="btn" onclick="appendToTextArea()">WhatsMyName</button>

<textarea id="txt-area" name="textarea"></textarea>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function appendToTextArea()
    {
        var button_name = $("#btn").text();//post title
        $("#txt-area").append(button_name); 

    }
</script>
```